# XSL From XML input

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML input and also XML output. I need to generate XSL. I have a problem with my XSL file. Can you help me please? Here is my XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odds>
    <sport name="Soccer">
        <region name="Europe">
            <competition name="UEFA Champions League">
                <event name="Real Madrid - FC Bayern München">
                    <market name="[Full Time] Money Line" suspended="false" id="216649202" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" inRunning="false">
                        <outcome name="Real Madrid" id="49234983" price="2.35"/>
                        <outcome name="Draw" id="49234984" price="3.6"/>
                        <outcome name="FC Bayern München" id="49234985" price="2.8"/>
                    </market>
                    <market name="[Next Round] To Qualify" suspended="true" id="21905536" expiry="2014-04-24T19:05:00Z" inRunning="false">
                        <selection name="Benfica" id="49951019" price="2.4"/>
                        <selection name="Juventus" id="49951020" price="1.5"/>
                    </market>
                </event>
            </competition>
        </region>
    </sport>
</odds>
```

And this is my XSL file:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@suspended"/>

<xsl:template match="market[@suspended='true']"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="market">
<market>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@name" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="@expiry" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="@inRunning" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="@id" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</market>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@inRunning[. = 'false']">
    <xsl:attribute name="inRunning">0</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="outcome">
  <selection >
   <xsl:copy-of select="@price" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="@id" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="@name" />
    <xsl:attribute name="handicap"></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </selection>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code is working by I need some changes in my OUTPUT. Here is my output

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odds>
    <sport name="Soccer">
        <region name="Europe">
            <competition name="UEFA Champions League">
                <event name="Real Madrid - FC Bayern München">
                    <market name="[Full Time] Money Line" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" inRunning="false" id="216649202">
                        <selection price="2.35" id="49234983" name="Real Madrid" handicap=""/>
                        <selection price="3.6" id="49234984" name="Draw" handicap=""/>
                        <selection price="2.8" id="49234985" name="FC Bayern München" handicap=""/>
                    </market>

                </event>
            </competition>
        </region>
    </sport>
</odds>
```

But this OUPUT must be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<odds>
  <group name="Soccer">
    <group name="Europe">
      <group name="UEFA Champions League">
        <group name="Real Madrid - FC Bayern München">
          <market name="[Full Time] Money Line" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" inRunning="0" id="216649202">
            <selection price="2.35" id="49234983" name="Real Madrid" handicap=""/>
            <selection price="3.6" id="49234984" name="Draw" handicap=""/>
            <selection price="2.8" id="49234985" name="FC Bayern München" handicap=""/>
          </market>
          </group>
      </group>
    </group>
  </group>
</odds>
```

What i must use, to change in output instead inRunning="false" to inRunning="0"?

Comment: Any reason you keep changing the code in the question? Please decide what you'd like to ask _before_ you post on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MathiasMüller sorry, because i found some answer already. Now this is final. What i must use, to change in output instead inRunning="false" to inRunning="0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change an attribute to have another value, simply add a template to match that attribute (with the old value) and create a new attribute with the new value.

Try adding this template to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="@inRunning[. = 'false']">
    <xsl:attribute name="inRunning">0</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the check is case-sensitive, so this particular example wouldn't match "FALSE" for example.

Also note you have to replace `<xsl:copy-of select="@inRunning" />` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="@inRunning" />` in your existing code for this to work.

Comment: Thank you! But i have small problem. When i add this code in my xslt, it worked, but when i put another code with ordering my attributes in "market", InRunning become again false instead "0". I updated my code in my 1 post.

Comment: Instead of doing `<xsl:copy-of select="@inRunning" />` do `<xsl:apply-templates select="@inRunning" />`. In fact, you should use `xsl:apply-templates` for creating all the attributes you need. (In fact, you might even be able to do `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />` rather than create them individually).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, but with this code, <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> i have different ordering on my attributes..

Comment: Ordering of attributes shouldn't really make a difference, but if they do, then you will have to on `xsl:apply-templates` on the attributes individually.

Comment: I have another question. I need to take from outcome Real Madrid this - "(-3.5)" and put this number to handicap and also add this to ID in market. Like this "21905549-3.5" Could you give me some advice?

Comment: My advice would be to ask a whole new question on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Note that I have rolled back your latest edit to how it was when I answered the question, otherwise my answer would have no longer have made sense.