# XSL From XML. XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to take a number from outcome Over this - "(0.5)" and put this number to handicap and also add this number at the end of ID in market. Like this: 219055430.5. Could you give me some advice?
Here is XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odds xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <sport name="Soccer">
  <region name="Europe">
   <competition name="UEFA Champions League">
    <event name="Real Madrid - FC Bayern München">
     <market name="[Full Time] Over/Under" suspended="false" id="21905543" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" inRunning="false">
      <outcome name="Over (0.5)" id="49954102" price="1" handicap=""/>
     </market>
    </event>
   </competition>
  </region>
 </sport>
</odds>
```

My XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@suspended"/>

<xsl:template match="market[@suspended='true']"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = '1X']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/Draw</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = '12']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'X2']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Draw/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'HWin-HWin']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/Real Madrid</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'HWin-Draw']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/Draw</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'Draw-HWin']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Draw/Real Madrid</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'AWin-AWin']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">FC Bayern München/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'AWin-Draw']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">FC Bayern München/Draw</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'Draw-AWin']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Draw/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'AWin-HWin']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">FC Bayern München/Real Madrid</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'HWin-AWin']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'Draw-Draw']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Draw/Draw</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="market">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="inRunning=false">
<market>
<xsl:copy-of select="@name" />
<xsl:copy-of select="@expiry" />
<xsl:attribute name="inRunning">1</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:copy-of select="@id" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</market>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<market>
<xsl:copy-of select="@name" />
<xsl:copy-of select="@expiry" />
<xsl:attribute name="inRunning">0</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:copy-of select="@id" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</market>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="outcome">
<selection >
<xsl:copy-of select="@price" />
<xsl:copy-of select="@id" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="@name" />
<xsl:attribute name="handicap"></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</selection>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this must be output:

```
        <market name="[Full Time] Over/Under" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" inRunning="0" id="219055430.5"> 
         <selection price="1" id="49954102" name="Over" handicap="0.5"/> 
        </market>
```

Comment: What's the connection to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28872752/1987598)? You are using the same XML document (yours isn't even well-formed) - which is an incredible coincidence.

Comment: @MathiasMüller yes, it is the same. Sorry. I formed it.

Comment: It seems like this question is the result of [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872752/xsl-from-xml-input#comment46013802_28873601) - did you create a new account for another question?

Comment: no, this is my friends acc, because i reached question limit

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the XSLT you have already tried? Also, will the `name` attribute on the `outcome` element always have the same format? Thanks.

Comment: @TimC, done, also i have a problem with my when statement. It doesnt work..Yes , it will have the same format.

Comment: Note, the reason the "when" statement doesn't work is that it looking for an element named "IsRunning", not an attribute. It should be `<xsl:when test="@inRunning='false'">`. However, you don't need the condition here. As mentioned in the answer to your previous question, if you use `<xsl:apply-templates select="@IsRunning"  />` to create the attribute, you could use a template match to change the value. Thanks!

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when it was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you need all that XSLT code. I am even less sure why *we* need to see all that code in order to get this question. If I am not mistaken, the following template will provide the required output all by itself:

```
<xsl:template match="market">
    <xsl:variable name="handicap" select="substring-before(substring-after(outcome/@name, ' ('), ')')" />
    <market name="{@name}" expiry="{@expiry}" inRunning="{number(@inRunning='true')}" id="{concat(@id, $handicap)}"> 
         <selection price="{outcome/@price}" id="{outcome/@id}" name="{substring-before(outcome/@name, ' (')}" handicap="{$handicap}"/> 
    </market>
</xsl:template>
```

When applied to your **example input**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odds xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <sport name="Soccer">
  <region name="Europe">
   <competition name="UEFA Champions League">
    <event name="Real Madrid - FC Bayern München">
     <market name="[Full Time] Over/Under" suspended="false" id="21905543" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" inRunning="false">
      <outcome name="Over (0.5)" id="49954102" price="1" handicap=""/>
     </market>
    </event>
   </competition>
  </region>
 </sport>
</odds>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<market name="[Full Time] Over/Under" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" inRunning="0" id="219055430.5">
   <selection price="1" id="49954102" name="Over" handicap="0.5"/>
</market>
```

If I *am* mistaken, that you will need to edit your question and spell out the rules for us.

Comment: I edit first post)) It was a little piece of output code. now it is how it must look like. `with your code i got only 1 line of output

Comment: The XSLT above, applied to your original input, produces (AFAICT) exactly the original requested output.  The important thing here is that it solves the problem (or rather problems) that you have presented. Now it's your place to implement this solution into your own, larger project. We are here to help you with the more difficult parts,  not to do your work for you.

Comment: but how i can output not only 1 line. for example if i have 2 or 3 lines in outcome?